# React and Styled Component - conditional styling based on current iteration

Tags: reactjs, iteration, styled-components

I'm trying to style images in my gallery based on properties that each image have. So far I found that this is working:

```
const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`

function Gallery({gallery}) {
  return (
    {gallery.map(image => {
      return (
        <ImageContainer 
          key={image.id} 
          style={{backgroundColor: (image.height > image.width) ? 'red' : 'blue'}}
        >
          <img src={image.thumb} alt="puppy" />
        </ImageContainer>
      )
    })}
  )
}
```

but I'm looking for something cleaner, like:

```
const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background-color: ${(image.height > image.width) ? 'red' : 'blue'}
`

function Gallery({gallery}) {
  return (
    {gallery.map(image => {
      return (
        <ImageContainer key={image.id}>
          <img src={image.thumb} alt="puppy" />
        </ImageContainer>
      )
    })}
  )
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to pass `height` and `width` as `props` to the styled component -

```js
const ImageContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background-color: ${({ height, width }) => (height > width) ? 'red' : 'blue'}
`

function Gallery({gallery}) {
  return (
    {gallery.map(image => {
      return (
        <ImageContainer key={image.id} height={image.height} width={image.width}>
          <img src={image.thumb} alt="puppy" />
        </ImageContainer>
      )
    })}
  )
}
```

You can find more information about passed props in `styled-components` right [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props).

Comment: Great!! It would be fantastic if you would accept my answer. People stumbling upon the question would have a less hard time figuring it out, if there is an accepted answer here. @DomanskaGrzyb

Comment: Sure thing! Done :)